# Syncing google drive in linux

Tags: ubuntu, dropbox, google-drive

I use Dropbox client for syncing files to the web, and it works reasonably well.  Now I want to purchase additional storage, but Dropbox is currently twice the price of google drive space!  That's enough for me to switch, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a client for my operating system (Ubuntu).

Is there any client for syncing files to google drive with file manager integration on Ubuntu?  Preferably free and open source.  [Syncany](http://www.syncany.org/) looked promising, but there doesn't seem to be any actual releases and I think the screenshots are just mock-ups from over a year ago, that project looks dying if not dead.

Comment: There is a CLI program, but none with File manager integration.

Answer (score 3):

While waiting an indefinite time for googles own sync clieent, these are the solutions around:

- [grive](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/grive-update-brings-full-google-drive.html) is free software, sync needs to be triggered manually
- insync is a proprietary service with advanced features, free only while in beta
- [google-drive-ocamlfuse](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/mount-google-drive-in-linux-with-google.html) does not really sync but rather mount your gDrive

Comment: [insync](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/google-drive-client-insync-for-linux.html)

Answer (score 2):

Google has promised to deliver a sync client for linux soon. But still google drive has problem of not syncing folders outside google drive folder, do upgrading storage for backup purpose resulted in vain for me.

Comment: Soon ... still waiting :)

Comment: ... still waiting :)

Comment: ... almost here :)

Comment: @TylerDurden yup a 5 year old comment. I'm also still waiting for same to get it working on my home pc :P

Answer (score 0):

I found this one.
https://github.com/odeke-em/drive/blob/master/platform_packages.md

you can't limit the bandwidth and it has no GUI but it's still easy to use. still it is good, especially if you have so many files like i do.

Comment: Could you include an example command?